# How do i give my un-released iPhone app to people who aren't near me to test?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, beta

This isn't a coding question, but is to to do with beta testing my app and so I think it's relevant for here.

I want to give my app to people to try, such as online friends and my parents, neither of whom live anywhere near me. Am i able to provision an iPod Touch or iPhone for testing my app, and put the app onto that iPod or iPhone without doing it directly from my computer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you need to generate an Ad-Hoc build. You get the beta testers to send you the UDID for their phones, then build an Ad-Hoc build targeting those devices and email it to them. They install it by dragging it into iTunes and then syncing their phone.

In reality it can be a bit of a trial the first time you generate an Ad-Hoc build. Apple's docs cover all the facts but lack a simple step-by-step guide. I'd strongly suggest you check out [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com/) - it's free to use and it makes the whole process much easier.

(If you're feeling really adventurous you could try out [Anticipation](https://github.com/simonwhitaker/anticipation), a simple Ad Hoc distribution tool I wrote that runs on Google App Engine. It's free and open source, so help yourself!)

Comment: FYI, the Apple docs @Simon is referring is the [iOS Development Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/145-Distributing_Applications/distributing_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH10-SW19) - see the "Publishing Your Application for Testing" section for more info. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `Ad Hoc Distribution` in [Provisioning Portal](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action). Basically, you will need to create an Ad Hoc Distribution Profile that  has the Unique Device ID's of the devices your friends will use to test.

In Xcode, you will build your app with the above-mentioned distribution file using **Build and Archive**. When You open Organizer and click on the archived app, you will choose Share -> Email. This will open your mail client and attach the `.ipa` and the correct distribution file for your users to drop onto iTunes and Sync.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You want to look in to Ad Hoc Distribution. You'll create an Ad Hoc Distribution Provisioning Profile on the Provisioning Portal, then Build & Archive, then "Share" the archive signed with your Ad Hoc profile.

Check out [this article](http://jeffreysambells.com/posts/2010/06/22/ios-wireless-app-distribution/), it walks you through it and shows a nice way to distribute it online. Note that you have to repeat the process every time you make a change to your app or add a new device to the profile.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an ad-hoc version of your app.

You need to get the UUID of the users devices. Erica Sadun created an [app](http://itunes.apple.com/de/app/ad-hoc-helper/id285691333?mt=8) that helps you doing this. It gets the uuid on the device and emails it to you. Those UUID goes into a special provisioning profile you create in the provisioning center on dev.apple.

For ad hoc deployment I use [Hockey Framework](http://buzzworks.de/blog/announcing-developer-framework-hockey). Some php files you put on your webserver with the ad hoc version and the provisioning profile.
Beta testers can then install the app by visiting the website with their devices.